# Browser-sync not injecting CSS for remote site

Tags: javascript, css, browser-sync

I need to do CSS styling of a remote site. I can't host the site locally for development, so I'd rather tweak the CSS locally and see the changes without having to wait for it to upload and then refresh the browser.

Seems like Browser-sync should be able to do this.

I set up a file bs.js:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

browserSync({  
  proxy: {target:'http://mysite.ca/'},   
  files: "css/*.css",
  serveStatic: ['css'] 
});
```

and run "node bs.js". It opens a browser window with URL http://localhost:3000/ displaying my remote site. So far so good, and if I make a change to my local custom.css (which is also on the remote site, with the same directory structure)  it displays "[Browsersync] File event [change]: css\custom.CSS"

However, nothing changes in the browser window. If I use chrome inspector, the contents of css\custom.CSS have not changed, though the file name has changed to custom.css?browsersync=1606353064487

Why won't it inject the changed CSS file?

Edit: Also, I can see that browser-sync has injected

```
    <script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.13'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
```

into the remote site so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need staticStatic set to the directory you are serving your local files from. Use rewrite rule if your local directory structure isn't the same as the remote site.  match parameter should be the path to the CSS file on the remote site.  The return parameter is the name of your local CSS file you will be serving. Seems like it is relative to the serveStatic path, so you don't put the full file path here.

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

browserSync({
  
  proxy: 'https://mysite.dev/',
 
  
files: "./themes/bootstrap_sass/css/*.css",
serveStatic: ['./themes/bootstrap_sass/css'],
rewriteRules: [
  {
    match: new RegExp('sites/mysite.dev/themes/bootstrap_sass/css/style.css'),
    fn: function() {
      return 'style.css';
    }
  }
]
 
});
```